# How to show Navigation Left bar button?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Developing an iOS application with Xcode ver 9.3, Swift.

Navigation Left bar button does not appear. Could you tell me how to show Left bar button?

When I tried the button on the right side with the same code, it displayed without any problem.

The code and the storyboard are as follows.

**Code of First TableView**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let naviButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "naviButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Tapped))

        // Left bar button does not appear
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = naviButton

        // Right bar button do appear
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = naviButton

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    @objc func Tapped() {
        print("Tapped")
    }

...
```

**Storyboard**

[image: Storyboard]

**Simulator**

[image]

Comment: add comments to this line `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = naviButton`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can not place same button twice in `UINavigationBar`. So create 2 separate button and then assign them to `leftbarButton` and `rightbarButton`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let leftNaviButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "lNaviButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Tapped1))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNaviButton

    let rightNaviButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "rNaviButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Tapped2))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightNaviButton
}

@objc func Tapped1() {
    print("Tapped1")
}

@objc func Tapped2() {
    print("Tapped2")
}
```

Comment: The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add the same view twice to the UI. If you create a single `UIBarButtonItem`, you can add it either as a left, OR as a right navigation item, but not both at the same time. So simply create another one if you want to have items at both sides:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let leftNaviButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "naviButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Tapped))

    // Left bar button does not appear
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNaviButton

    let rightNaviButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "naviButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Tapped))
    // Right bar button do appear
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightNaviButton

}
```

Comment: The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As I suggest in my comment your issue is related to the fact that your are setting the same `UIBarButtonItem` for both `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` and `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` you need to create two `UIBarButtonItem` and assign one for right and the other for left, I think that you know how do this ;)

Comment: The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a one extension for UIButton like

```
extension UIButton {
    class func addBarButton(tittle:String,_ target: Any, action: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem{
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle(tittle, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    }    
}
```

and you main controller just you have to write below code

```
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIButton.addBarButton(tittle: "RNaviButton", self, action: #selector(Tapped1))
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIButton.addBarButton(tittle: "LNaviButton", self, action: #selector(Tapped2))
```

and action method for button

```
@objc func Tapped1() {
    print("Tapped1")
}
@objc func Tapped2() {
    print("Tapped2")
}
```

If you want same action for both button you can do it also passing same action in both button action.